# MyModel.objects.update_or_create() --> Boolean wether data was updated or not?

Tags: django, django-models

AFAIK Django does not provide a generic way to see if data was changed by [update_or_create()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create)

The boolean `created` tells me that a row was created. But how can I know if data was changed (SQL UPDATE which changed data)

Example:

```
obj, created = MyModel.update_or_create(pk=12345,
                       defaults=dict(name='Doctor Zhivago'))
```

There are three cases:

1. `obj` was created. No problem, I have the boolean variable `created`
2. `obj` was not created, it was updated. For example the previous name was "Machuca".
3. `obj` was not created and not updated. For example the previous name was already "Doctor Zhivago".

I can't distinguish between case2 and case3 at the moment.

Comment: Er, because it wasn't created?

Comment: @DanielRoseman If you ("guru" in my eyes) don't understand my question, then there is something missing. I made it more verbose.

Comment: A similar scenario was brought up a few months 'To avoid having update_or_create(), perform an update when there were no changes to the object' , there's a patch https://github.com/django/django/pull/7418  , but it appears it isn't going to make it into a release for lack of testing and backward compatibility.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Feeling a bit inspired by @bakkal, I've written a mixin class that you can apply to a custom Manager class, then assign that custom Manager to your `MyModel` class.  This changes the format of the returned tuple to `(obj, created, updated)`.  In the loop over the values in `defaults.items()` I am checking if any of the new values are different from the old values.

```
class UpdateOrCreateMixin(object):
    def update_or_create_v2(self, defaults=None, **kwargs):
        """
        Look up an object with the given kwargs, updating one with defaults
        if it exists, otherwise create a new one.
        Return a tuple (object, created, updated), where created and updated are 
        booleans specifying whether an object was created.
        """
        defaults = defaults or {}
        lookup, params = self._extract_model_params(defaults, **kwargs)
        self._for_write = True
        with transaction.atomic(using=self.db):
            try:
                obj = self.select_for_update().get(**lookup)
            except self.model.DoesNotExist:
                obj, created = self._create_object_from_params(lookup, params)
                if created:
                    return obj, created, False
            updated = False
            for k, v in defaults.items():
                oldattr = getattr(obj, k)
                if oldattr != (v() if callable(v) else v):
                    updated = True
                setattr(obj, k, v() if callable(v) else v)
            obj.save(using=self.db)
        return obj, False, updated

class CustomManager(UpdateOrCreateMixin, models.Manager):
    pass

class MyModel(models.Model)
    field = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    objects = CustomManager()

obj, created, updated = MyModel.objects.update_or_create_v2(pk=12345,
                   defaults=dict(name='Doctor Zhivago'))
```

Comment: this would be better if it didn't do the save when there's nothing to update maybe?

Comment: You are correct, removing that save call if `updated == False` would make sense.

Answer (score 2):

Given how that interface is implemented, there's no way to tell if the object has been updated or not if it's created. Because it always calls `save()` in that case.

Here's how `update_or_create()` is currently implemented:

```
    with transaction.atomic(using=self.db):
        try:
            obj = self.select_for_update().get(**lookup)
        except self.model.DoesNotExist:
            obj, created = self._create_object_from_params(lookup, params)
            if created:
                return obj, created

        # [below part always runs the same if obj was not created]
        for k, v in defaults.items():
            setattr(obj, k, v() if callable(v) else v)
        obj.save(using=self.db)
    return obj, False
```

Ref. https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/query.py#L459

As you can see when the object is not created, the way it's implemented can't tell if it was updated or not.

However you could manually verify if your lookup/update values are different from those on the existing object in the DB before caling `save()`, and then set an `updated` flag.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using mixed approach to handling this type of tasks:

I have `last_edited` or `last_modified` field on model without `auto_now=True`.

Instead of `auto_now` I use [django-dirtyfields](https://github.com/romgar/django-dirtyfields) and inside `save` method I do something like this:

```
def save(*args, **kwargs):
    if self.is_dirty():
        self.last_modified = now()
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

If you don't like the mess in `save` method, you can use `pre_save` signal and update `last_modified` there based on dirty fields.

Then after calling `update_or_create` you can pretty safely rely on `last_modified` field in order to check if model was indeed modified.

dirtyfield's api is pretty simple, you can play with it without too much setup pain.